# Read JSON file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am building a web application in ASP.NET and I am relatively really new to programming. I am very confused on how to read objects in a JSON file(using C#) and use them in web application. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Hi Keith please help us help you by searching your question first. For example, I just entered "how to read objects in a JSON file(using C#)" in the search bar and got __75 results__.

Comment: As a kind suggestion and to avoid getting down votes, you may want to remove your own question and look at those other answers, coming back only if there is something you still do not understand.

Comment: As a sugestion you can do some search on questions related here in SO, if you came out with an specific case, show some code or what you have done so far and post a question targeting an specific problem . Welcome aboard

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to read in the JSON but the standard way would be to use a JSON serialiser to serialise the document into a c# class structure.

This works well when you know the structure of the json file. See [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for a very well known JSON library. There are others out there if you want something different.

If you need to figure out what the structure of your document is, then you could also use a tool like [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) which will create the c# class structure for you.

If you didn't know the structure of the file up front then you could still use the NewtonSoft library but would need to do a few extra steps and things tend to get tricky. 
*I am not sure this is within the scope of your question.*

Answer (score 0):

NewtonSoft (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library is great for this, I recommend taking a look at it, specifically:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

For examples of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend library: [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). It is so easy to use.